# How can I image_read multiple images at once?

Tags: r, image, imagemagick

In order to create a .gif using the magick package, how could I read multiple images at once?

I'm importing them succesfully in a list object, but getting an error from `image_animate()`.

```
# read all files in folder (only .png files)
capturas <- list.files("./path/to/images/")

# get all images in a list
images <- vector()
for (i in seq_along(capturas)) {
  images[i] <- list(image_read(str_c("./path/to/images/", capturas[i])))}

image_animate(image_scale(images, "500x500"), fps = 1, dispose = "previous")
```

Getting the following error:

```
> image_animate(image_scale(images, "500x500"), fps = 2, dispose = "previous")
Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.
```

While using `image_read` on each image separately works OK...

```
img_1 <- image_read(str_c("./path/to/images/", capturas[1]))
img_2 <- image_read(str_c("./path/to/images/", capturas[2]))
img_3 <- image_read(str_c("./path/to/images/", capturas[3]))
img <- c(img_1, img_2, img_3)
img <- image_scale(img, "300x300")
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. Above `for`, do `images <- vector("list", length(capturas))`. Then, in the body of your loop, do `images[i] <- image_read(str_c("./path/to/images/", capturas[i]))` assuming that all that stuff (`image_read` and so on) is correct.

Comment: When doing that I get this error: `Error in images[i] <- image_read(str_c("./path/to/images/",  : cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'list'`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `image_join` from the magick package to create a multi-frame image you can use in the `image_animate` command. I used the `purrr` package instead of a loop.

```
library(purrr)
library(magick)
capturas <- list.files("./path/to/images/", pattern = "\\.png$")

# get all images in a list
images <- map(capturas, image_read)
images <- image_join(images)

image_animate(images, fps = 1, dispose = "previous")
```

Comment: How can you save the output of image_animate?

Comment: `myanimation <- image_animate(images, fps = 1, dispose = "previous")`, then: `image_write(myanimation, "myfilename.gif")`

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
library(magick)

#Get the list of all images: (".jpg", ".png", etc) 
allFiles = list.files(path = "./path/to/images/", pattern = ".jpg", full.names = T)

#Get the dataframe with info
allInfo = image_info(image_read(allFiles))

#Read the images 
my_images = image_read(allFiles)
```

Adapted from: https://community.rstudio.com/t/import-multiple-images-in-a-folder-and-image-info/43129/2

In case animation is wanted:

```
animation <- image_animate(image_scale(my_images, "200x200"), fps = 1) 
animation
```

To save the animation:

```
image_write(animation, "./path/to/output/test1.gif")
```