# How to clean multiple magick images

Tags: r, imagemagick, tesseract

I have a pdf with multiple pages, my goal is to bring that pdf, convert to image, clean and process the text in OCR. I have it working well with one, but with multiple, I can't map or `lapply` the magickimage:

```
multi_images <- map(multi_file_list, image_read)

image_cleaner <- function(images){

  images <- map(images, function(x){

images %>%
      image_crop(geometry_area(width = 1290, height = 950, y_off = 285, x_off = 380)) %>%  
      image_write(format = 'png', density = '300x300') %>%
      tesseract::ocr(tesseract(options = list(preserve_interword_spaces = 1)))



  })


}
```

gives the expected error:

```
Error: `.x` must be a vector, not a `magick-image` object
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

So how can I access the magick-image list of objects? I note there isn't an answer to [this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612276/how-can-i-image-read-multiple-images-at-once) question

Answer (score 1):

This worked, note I changed `map` to `Map`

Also your function should have called `x` inside the loop

```
image_cleaner <- function(images){
    Map(function(x){
        # change images %>% 
        # to 
        # x %>%
        x %>%
            image_crop(geometry_area(width = 1290, height = 950, y_off = 285, x_off = 380)) %>%  
            image_write(format = 'png', density = '300x300') %>%
            tesseract::ocr(tesseract(options = list(preserve_interword_spaces = 1)))

    }, images)


}

dat <- image_cleaner(multi_images)

> mapply(nchar,dat, USE.NAMES = F)
[1]  12 288 124
```

Comment: Ah, got it. I'll test it out and get back to you.

Comment: No problem. I will say that when I'm performing OCR on batches of PDFs, unless I need to create a corpus, I will usually combine them all in my first step and then normalize only once

Comment: my process now is ```pdftools::pdf-convert()``` to create images of each PDF page, ```image_read``` as seen here, processing (normalizing?), then clean text a bit with stringr. Are you saying that I should bring in all PDF into the same image batch, and run through this cleaning process once, and separate the ocr() into a new stage? I have many 2-3mb pdf's so welcome any advice on workflow.

Comment: What OS are you on? I run linux, so i use a cli tool to combine the files first, calling with `system`

Comment: Mac, so would be a bit different but can use the same general process I believe

Comment: The function here using Map is running it only across the first page of the magick object, but it has 5 listed, so isn't looping through as expected